# How to constrain some variables in pyomo?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I´m working on a optimization problem (state-tasks networks) using pyomo. I'm using the base example as described in the Github notebook [Scheduling Multipurpose Batch Processes using State-Task Networks](https://jckantor.github.io/ND-Pyomo-Cookbook/04.05-Scheduling-Multipurpose-Batch-Processes-using-State-Task_Networks.html).

I've simplified the problem to reduce the number of tasks and states as follows:

```
Kodili = {
    # time grid
    'TIME':  range(0, H+1),
    
    # states
    'STATES': {
        'Feed_A'   : {'capacity': 500, 'initial': 500, 'price':  0},
        'Product_1': {'capacity': 500, 'initial':   0, 'price': 10}
        },
    
    # state-to-task arcs indexed by (state, task)
    'ST_ARCS': {
        ('Feed_A',   'Reaction_1')   : {'rho': 1.0},
        ('Feed_A',   'Reaction_2')   : {'rho': 1.0},
        ('Feed_A',   'Reaction_3')   : {'rho': 1.0},
    },
    
    # task-to-state arcs indexed by (task, state)
    'TS_ARCS': {
        ('Reaction_1', 'Product_1')   : {'dur': 2, 'rho': 1},
        ('Reaction_2', 'Product_1')   : {'dur': 2, 'rho': 1},
        ('Reaction_3', 'Product_1')   : {'dur': 2, 'rho': 1}
    },
    
    # unit data indexed by (unit, task)
    'UNIT_TASKS': {
        ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_1'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  80, 'Cost': 1, 'vCost': 0, 'Tclean': 0},
        ('Reactor_1', 'Reaction_3'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  20, 'Cost': 1, 'vCost': 0, 'Tclean': 0},
        ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_2'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  30, 'Cost': 1, 'vCost': 0, 'Tclean': 0},
        ('Reactor_2', 'Reaction_3'): {'Bmin': 0, 'Bmax':  50, 'Cost': 1, 'vCost': 0, 'Tclean': 0},
    },
}
```

The problem I have is that I simply need to add a constraint that *forces* some units to operate "**simultanously**" on the same task.

Basically the rules I need to add are:

- Reactor 1 could perform Reaction 1 (done)
- Reactor 2 could perform Reaction 2 (done)
- Reactor 1 and Reactor 2 could perform Reaction 3 (but needs to be at the same time)

**The key rule to add is:** Reaction 3 could only be performed by Reactor 1 and Reactor 2 at the same time. (***If Reactor 1 works on Reaction 3, then Reactor 2 must be working also on Reaction 3 at the same time and for the same amount of time***)

I have tried to modify the proposed constraints to limit that one unit can only be allocated to one task. I have added something like "i!=x" so that this rule only applies to different tasks.

```
for j in UNITS:
    for t in TIME:
        lts = 0
        for i in I[j]:
            for x in I[j]:
                for tprime in TIME:
                    if i!=x and tprime >= (t-p[i]+1-UNIT_TASKS[(j,i)]['Tclean']) and tprime <= t: 
                        lts += model.W[i,j,tprime]
        model.cons.add(lts <= 1)
```

But definitely it doesn't seem to be the right direction. The results I'm obtaining are:

```
    Reactor_1                   Reactor_2
0   ('Reaction_1', 80.0)    
1                               ('Reaction_3', 50.0) <-- This couldn't be a solution
2   ('Reaction_1', 80.0)    
3                               ('Reaction_2', 30.0)
4   ('Reaction_1', 80.0)    
5
```

and I'm looking for something like:

```
    Reactor_1                   Reactor_2
0   ('Reaction_1', 80.0)    
1   ('Reaction_3', 80.0)        ('Reaction_3', 50.0) <-- Something like this must be the output for R3
2   ('Reaction_1', 80.0)    
3                               ('Reaction_2', 30.0)
4   ('Reaction_1', 80.0)    
5
```

Any ideas about how to add these constraints?

Comment: It looks like your bounds on tprime are backwards. From the link, tprime should be `>= t` and `<= t - p_i +1`

Comment: Updated link not needed - it is actually the same with the one in the question; as a general rule, in such cases it is preferable to update the question itself (comments might get deleted any time).